# how to record between key input delay?

Tags: python

When I run the code below, I have noticed that what key is entered is recorded.
But there is one more thing I want.
That's for example, assuming I typed a and b, I want the time between a and b to be recorded between the keys as well.

```
import pynput, time

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

count = 0
keys = []

def on_press(key):
    global keys, count

    keys.append(key)
    count += 1
    print("{0} pressed".format(key))

    if count >= 10:
        count = 0
        write_file(keys)
        keys = []

def write_file(keys):
    with open("log.txt", "w") as f:
        for key in keys:
            k = str(key).replace("'", "")
            if k.find("space") > 0:
                f.write('\n')
            elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                f.write(k)

def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I sloved question.
Thanks for everyone.

```
# From: https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging
import keyboard, sys, os
import time

on_press_previous = 0

log_dir = ""

os.remove(log_dir + 'key_log.txt')
logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "key_log.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')

def on_press(key):
    global on_press_previous
    on_press_current = time.time()
    delta = round(on_press_current - on_press_previous, 3)
    on_press_previous = on_press_current

    logging.info('{0}'.format(key))
    logging.info('{0}'.format(delta))
    if keyboard.is_pressed("F7"):
        sys.exit()

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can track the time for the `on_press` event, store it, and then calculated the difference. Here I am using a global variable just for simplicity and consistency with your existing code. Library function `time.time_ns()` should give plenty of resolution.

```
import pynput, time

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

count = 0
keys = []
on_press_previous = 0

def on_press(key):
    global keys, count, on_press_previous

    # current timestamp in nanoseconds
    on_press_current = time.time_ns()

    # calculate delta from previous on_press event
    delta = on_press_current - on_press_previous

    # store the current timestamp for the next round
    on_press_previous = on_press_current

    keys.append((key,delta))
    count += 1
    print("{} pressed {} nanoseconds from previous".format(key, delta))

    if count >= 10:
        count = 0
        write_file(keys)
        keys = []

def write_file(keys):
    with open("log.txt", "w") as f:
        for key,delta in keys:
            k = str(key).replace("'", "")
            if k.find("space") > 0:
                f.write('\n')
            elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                f.write(k)
                f.write(str(delta))

def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try as fast as I can.

Comment: The `write_file` function will need fixes, to write both `key,delta` values.

Comment: Updated with some fixes.

Comment: f.write(delta)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int

Comment: Change, use `f.write(str(delta))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `Timer` class I use to count / record time when writing programs:

```
class Timer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = None
        self.on = False

    def start(self):
        # start counting
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.on = True

    def value(self):
        # --- return current value ---
        if self.on:
            return time.time() - self.start_time
        return 0

    def tostr(self):
        # --- return value as {min:sec} format ---
        val = math.floor(self.value())
        mins = '0' + str(int(val / 60)) if len(str(int(val / 60))) == 1 else str(int(val / 60))
        secs = '0' + str(val % 60) if len(str(val % 60)) == 1 else str(val % 60)
        return "{}:{}".format(mins, secs)

    def stop(self):
        # --- stop counting ---
        self.__init__()
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try as fast as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Use `timeit` module (`import timeit`):

Put this two lines in `on_press`:

```
print("The time difference is :", timeit.default_timer() - start)
start = timeit.default_timer()
```

Now it will print out time difference between two button clicks:

```
count = 0
keys = []
start = timeit.default_timer()

def on_press(key):
    global keys, count, start
    ...
    ...
```

---

Also you will have to declare new `global` variable `start`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try as fast as I can.